# Basic Apache commands for a local Windows machine

Tags: apache, console, restart

I have installed XAMPP on my Windows 7 machine and created a number of virtual servers. This part is straightforward enough.

Each time I add a new virtual server I am having to reboot my computer in order to reboot the Apache server, which is of course quite time consuming.

I have googled and found the correct console commands to use to reboot Apache, but absolutely non of the references that I have found actually tell you where to type the relevant commands! A certain level of knowledge is assumed.

So my question is - where do I actually type `apache -k restart`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Going back to absolute basics here. The answers on this page and a little googling have brought me to the following resolution to my issue.
Steps to restart the apache service with Xampp installed:-

1. Click the start button and type CMD (if on Windows Vista or later and Apache is installed as a service make sure this is an [elevated command prompt](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-elevated-command-prompt/))
2. In the command window that appears type `cd C:\xampp\apache\bin` (the default installation path for Xampp)
3. Then type `httpd -k restart`

I hope that this is of use to others just starting out with running a local Apache server.

Comment: httpd -k -restart will not restart your Apache server, as it is a typo.  It should be httpd -k restart

Comment: i tried this but cmd just goes to the next line. doesnt return anything and apache doesnt then start.

Answer (score 3):

For frequent uses of this command I found it easy to add the location of `C:\xampp\apache\bin` to the `PATH`. Use whatever directory you have this installed in.

Then you can run from any directory in command line:

```
httpd -k restart
```

The answer above that suggests httpd -k -restart is actually a typo. You can see the commands by running `httpd /?`