# Can't import database through phpmyadmin file size too large

Tags: mysql, database, apache, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have been trying to import Database through phpMyAdmin. My database file is `a.sql` and it's size is 1.2 GB 
I am trying to import this on local and phpMyAdmin is saying:

> You probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit.

Please help I really need this to work.

Comment: did you refer to the documentation? do you have shell access to your server?

Comment: Best [Ans](http://www.steptoinstall.com/import-big-database-sql-file-to-phpmyadmin-wamp-server.html)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Its due to PHP that has a file size restriction for uploads.

If you have terminal/shell access then the above answers @Kyotoweb will work.

one way to get it done is that you create an .htaccess/ini file file to change PHP settings to get the sql file uploaded through PHPmyAdmin.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 120M //file size
php_value post_max_size 120M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Note you should remove this file after upload.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked but I more option was needed, we have to add a variable ($cfg ['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;)which we have to declare in c:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php.    I am providing the links here (http://www.john-dugan.com/?p=638)

Comment: Or you can edit /etc/php.ini in RedHat 6.6 using the same directives above , always restart apache such as: sudo service httpd restart in RedHat.

Comment: where this ini file should be created. Is in PHPmyAdmin folder?

Comment: @AbelJojo, This answer is bad, look here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38607904/4684797

Answer (score 98):

For Upload large size data in using phpmyadmin
Do following steps.

1. Open php.ini file from C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin    Update
   following lines

   ```
   max_execution_time = 259200
   max_input_time = 259200
   memory_limit = 1000M
   upload_max_filesize = 750M
   post_max_size = 750M
   ```

   than after restart wamp server or restart all services    Now Upload
   data using import function in phymyadmin.    Apply second step if
   till not upload data.
2. open config.default.php file in
   c:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\libraries    (Open this file accoring
   to phpmyadmin version)
   Find `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;`Replace to `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`
   Now you can upload data.

You can also upload large size database using MySQL Console as below.

1. Click on WampServer Icon -> MySQL -> MySQL Consol
2. Enter your database password like `root` in popup
3. Select database name for insert data by writing command `USE DATABASENAME`
4. Then load source sql file as `SOURCE C:\FOLDER\database.sql`
5. Press enter for insert data.

**Note**: You can't load a compressed database file e.g. `database.sql.zip` or `database.sql.gz`, you have to extract it first. Otherwise the console will just crash.

Comment: +1 for mysql console. 600mb database imported in 30 seconds. Using xampp, method: `cmd` > `cd {xampp_dir}/mysql/bin` > `mysql -h localhost -u root {db_name}` > enter password then step 4 from above solution.

Comment: If using xampp, then the php.ini file will be found at `C:\xampp\php`.

Answer (score 37):

Here is what I've done:

1. Gone to my XAMPP installed directoy `C:\xampp\php`
2. Open the "Configuration Settings" file named `php.ini` using your text editor, preferably you can also you Notepad for Windows machine.
3. Somewhere nearby on line no 886, please update it to `upload_max_filesize = 128M`
4. Similarly on line no 735 `post_max_size = 128M`
5. On line no 442 `max_execution_time = 300`
6. On line no 452 `max_input_time = 60`
7. Restart your Apache from either XAMPP Control Panel or using CMD in Windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723485/969092

Done!

Comment: Had the same problem as the OP.  This solution worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, saw a whole bunch of other more complicated answers and this worked great.

Comment: how to do it in mac, I did't find `php.ini` file in my `xampp\php` folder

Answer (score 22):

Use command line :

```
mysql.exe -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASENAME < MYDATABASE.sql
```

where MYDATABASE.sql is your sql file.

Comment: how would you do this if you only had FTP access to the server?

Comment: @Kyotoweb There's no space between the -p and PASSWORD on the command line (I can't edit your post because the change is only one character).

Comment: @ninesided He's talking about WAMP and local. Just gave him the fastest solution to his problem taking in consideration is environment.

Comment: aah I didn't spot the WAMP - the OP didn't mention local, but I guess most Windows server providers allow RDP, so that may be largely irrelevant

Comment: When using this option just make sure that you run the script in the folder where the .sql file is stored e.g C: \downloads>mysql.exe -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME < MYDATABASE.sql

Answer (score 9):

1. Set the below values in `php.ini` file (`C:\xampp\php\`)

   - `max_execution_time = 0`
   - `max_input_time=259200`
   - `memory_limit = 1000M`
   - `upload_max_filesize = 750M`
   - `post_max_size = 750M`
2. Open config.default file(C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default) and set the value as below:

   - $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
3. Then open the config.inc file(C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc). and paste below line:

   - `$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';`
4. Go to phpMyAdmin(`C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin`) folder and create folder called `upload` and paste your database to newly created upload folder (don't need to zip)
5. Lastly, go to phpMyAdmin and upload your db (Please select your database in drop-down)

[image: upload image]

6. That's all baby ! :)

***It takes lot of time.In my db(266mb) takes 50min to upload. So be patient ! ***

Answer (score 7):

If you are using MySQL in Xampp then do the steps below.

Find the following in XAMPP control panel>Apach-Config> PHP (php.ini) file

- post_max_size = 8M
- upload_max_filesize = 2M
- max_execution_time = 30
- ut_time = 60`enter code here` memory_limit = 8M

And change their sizes according to your need. 
I'm using these values

```
post_max_size = 30M
upload_max_filesize = 30M
max_execution_time = 4500
max_input_time = 4500
memory_limit = 850M
```

Comment: user friendly solution

Answer (score 4):

Another option that nobody here has mentioned yet is to do a staggered load of the database using a tool like [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) to work around the limit. It's a simple PHP script that loads a chunk of the database at a time before restarting itself and moving on the the next chunk.

Answer (score 4):

For ubuntu 14.04 use this:

1. Open `php.ini` using gedit or nano:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
   ```
2. Find `upload_max_size` then replace this single line with these lines:

   ```
   max_execution_time = 259200
   max_input_time = 259200
   memory_limit = 1000M
   upload_max_filesize = 750M
   post_max_size = 750M
   ```
3. Save `php.ini` and close editor
4. Restart apache2:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
5. Now open `localhost://phpmyadmin/` in browser and upload your `database.sql`

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I have Ubuntu 18.04 and for me path to `php.ini` was `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

You no need to edit `php.ini` or any thing.
I suggest best thing as Just use **MySQL WorkBench**.

JUST FOLLOW THE STEPS.

Install MySQL WorkBench 6.0

And In "Navigation panel"(Left side) there is option call 'Data import' under "MANAGEMENT". Click that and [follow steps below]

1. click Import Self-Contained File and choose your SQL file
2. Go to My Document and create folder call `"dump"[simple]`.
3. now you ready to upload file. Click IMPORT Button on down.

Answer (score 1):

to import big database into phpmyadmin there are two ways 
1 increase file execution size from php.ini
2 use command line to import big database.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try compressing (zipping) the file.  It sometimes works for me if I can't get to php.ini for phpmyadmin.  If zipping reduces the file size below the maximum file size, it just might work!

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

- Use another way to get the file on the server, and use a mysql client on the server
- Use another client to connect to the server and load the data
- Change your PHP settings to allow such huge files. Don't forget to increment the execution time as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the settings or play with command line.
There is option to compress the file and upload in phpMyAdmin. It should bring down the size considerably.

Comment: this actually helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put this here as I just updated my databases in xampp after several tries and reading the answers here. I used the Xampp 7.4
I tried to edit the `ExecTimeLimit` variable in config.default.php but still kept timing out and finally when I looked at the code I realized that if you put it to 0 it ill still default to 300. So you need to put it to actual high value to have a longer timeout.

```
 /**
 * @param array<int|string, mixed> $settings
 *
 * @psalm-return 0|positive-int
 */
private function setExecTimeLimit(array $settings): int
{
    if (! isset($settings['ExecTimeLimit'])) {
        return 300;
    }

    $execTimeLimit = (int) $settings['ExecTimeLimit'];

    return $execTimeLimit >= 0 ? $execTimeLimit : 300;
}
```