# How to import large sql file in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to import a sql file of approx 12 mb. But its causing problem while loading. Is there any way to upload it without splitting the sql file ?

Comment: use some mysql tools such as `mysql workbench` or `mysql Yog`

Comment: you can also see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593128/cant-import-database-through-phpmyadmin-file-size-too-large

Dunn.

Comment: If you cannot use the mysql console, there is an interesting solution which comes from phpmyadmin documentation: http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump

Comment: see video here https://youtu.be/eTpVItabrjY

Answer (score 133):

Try to import it from mysql console as per the taste of your OS.

```
mysql -u {DB-USER-NAME} -p {DB-NAME} < {db.file.sql path}
```

or if it's on a remote server use the -h flag to specify the host.

```
mysql -u {DB-USER-NAME} -h {MySQL-SERVER-HOST-NAME} -p {DB-NAME} < {db.file.sql path}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for revert guys. I make changes in php.ini and zip the file. It works for me :)

Comment: fastest way to do this!

Comment: if you are working locally you might consider my answer further down

Comment: This is a great answer. For anyone who might not be super savvy, you can just upload your DB file to your file manager on your host, then use SSH on your host to operate locally. This is much easier than installing `mysql` on your server for just one migration. Thanks for the help guys! (Also, I didn't need brackets)

Comment: For those who are wondering, you need to browse to your MySQL/bin folder to run the command. Worked great. Thanks.

Comment: ERROR: Unknown command '\U'. error(mysql -u {root} -p {test} < {C:\Users\sandeep\Desktop\pincode.sql})

Comment: @SandeepGarapati remove curly brackets.

Comment: What about that they do not have a password? using the database with default user name root? Using this command it is asking for the password.

Comment: @Hkachhia just hit enter when prompted.

Answer (score 93):

3 things you have to do:

in `php.ini` of your php installation (note: depending if you want it for CLI, apache, or nginx, find the right php.ini to manipulate)

```
post_max_size=500M

upload_max_filesize=500M

memory_limit=900M
```

or set other values.

**Restart/reload** apache if you have apache installed or php-fpm for nginx if you use nginx.

**Remote server?**

increase `max_execution_time` as well, as it will take time to upload the file.

**NGINX installation?**

you will have to add: `client_max_body_size 912M;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to the `http{...}` block

Comment: CORRECT - answer. Those 3 lines were must

Comment: This must be added to your apache directory, not the cli directory (at least as tested on my Ubuntu box)

Comment: changing this for `/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini` didn't work

Comment: @RickSanchez you sure you run this php version on apache? please run `phpinfo()` and verify that the values have been set correctly and the server was restarted

Comment: Dont forget to raise the max_execution_time value in php ini and restart apache

Answer (score 69):

Edit the config.inc.php file located in the phpmyadmin directory. In my case it is located at `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\config.inc.php`.

Find the line with `$cfg['UploadDir']` on it and update it to `$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';`

Then, create a directory called ‘upload’ within the phpmyadmin directory (for me, at `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\upload\`).

Then place the large SQL file that you are trying to import into the new `upload` directory. Now when you go onto the db import page within phpmyadmin console you will notice a drop down present that wasn’t there before – it contains all of the sql files in the upload directory that you have just created. You can now select this and begin the import.

If you’re not using WAMP on Windows, then I’m sure you’ll be able to adapt this to your environment without too much trouble.

Reference : http://daipratt.co.uk/importing-large-files-into-mysql-with-phpmyadmin/comment-page-4/

Comment: With more recent versions of phpMyAdmin, the $cfg['UploadDir'] var isn't there at all; however, this solution still works by just adding the var on a new line in the file.

Comment: The var is found in `config.default.php`, of the same dir, am using phpmyadmin version 4.6.4

Comment: Could not edit the previous comment anymore, the dir is `libraries/config.default.php`

Comment: wonderful solution after spending two days trying the MySQL command line with failure results.

Answer (score 28):

Solution for LINUX USERS (run with sudo)

Create 'upload' and 'save' directories:

```
mkdir /etc/phpmyadmin/upload
mkdir /etc/phpmyadmin/save
chmod a+w /etc/phpmyadmin/upload
chmod a+w /etc/phpmyadmin/save
```

Then edit phpmyadmin's config file:

```
gedit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Finally add absolute path for both 'upload' and 'save' directories:

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/etc/phpmyadmin/upload';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '/etc/phpmyadmin/save';
```

Now, just drop files on `/etc/phpmyadmin/upload` folder and then you'll be able to select them from phpmyadmin.

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: With this method phpmyadmin is giving me a `File could not be read!` message when I click the submit button on the upload form. In the middle of troubleshooting this now.

Comment: @JoeRocc did you find a solution for your issue? Perhaps it's a permission or ownership problem. Try with `sudo chmod 777 your-filename.sql`

Comment: 775. Not 777.
One should NOT advise to set 777 to get things working on a live server. It has security issues.

Answer (score 20):

Just one line and you are done (make sure mysql command is available as global or just go to mysql installation folder and enter into bin folder)

```
mysql -u database_user_name -p -D database_name < complete_file_path_with_file_name_and_extension
```

Here

- `u` stands for User
- `p` stands for Password
- `D` stands for Database

---DON'T FORGET TO ADD `<` SIGN AFTER DATABASE NAME---

Complete file path with name and extension can be like

`c:\folder_name\"folder name"\sql_file.sql`

---IF YOUR FOLDER AND FILE NAME CONTAINS SPACE THAN BIND THEM USING DOUBLE QUOTE---

Tip and Note: You can write your password after `-p` but this is not recommended because it will show to others who are watching your screen at that time, if you don't write there it will ask you when you will execute command by pressing enter.

Answer (score 9):

Create a zip or tar file and upload in phpmyadmin thats it..!

Answer (score 8):

I was able to import a large `.sql` file by having the following configuration in `httpd.conf` file:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted

    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
    php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
    php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
    php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 6):

I dont understand why nobody mention the easiest way....just split the large file with http://www.rusiczki.net/2007/01/24/sql-dump-file-splitter/
and after just execute vie mySQL admin the seperated generated files starting from the one with Structure

Comment: Great alternative, but not the easiest.  Easiest is simply uploading the huge import file into a specified upload directory, and then selecting file for import via phpMyAdmin, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19923060/888177

Answer (score 6):

PHPmyadmin also accepts compressed files in gzip format, so you can gzip the file (Use [7Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) if you don't have any) and upload the zipped file. Since its a text file, it will have a good compress ratio.

Answer (score 5):

Ok you use PHPMyAdmin but sometimes the best way is through terminal:

- Connect to database: `mysql -h localhost -u root -p` (switch root and localhost for user and database location)
- Start import from dump: `\. /path/to/your/file.sql`
- Go take a coffe and brag about yourself because you use terminal.

And that's it. Just remember if you are in a remote server, you must upload the .sql file to some folder.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to edit the php.ini file. change the following `upload_max_filesize` `post_max_size` to accommodate your file size.

Trying running `phpinfo()` to see their current value. If you are not at the liberty to change the php.ini file directly try  [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

If that is also not an option, you might like to give [bigdump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) a try.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use the command line;

`mysql -h yourhostname -u username -p databasename < yoursqlfile.sql`

Just ensure the path to the **SQL** file to import is stated explicitly.

In my case, I used this;

`mysql -h localhost -u root -p databasename < /home/ejalee/dumps/mysqlfile.sql`

Voila! you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on an article and this worked best for me

1. Open up the config.inc.php file within the phpmyadmin dir with your favorite code editor. In your local MAMP environment, it should be located here:

Hard Drive » Applications » MAMP » bin » config.inc.php

2. Do a search for the phrase `$cfg[‘UploadDir’]` – it’s going to look like this:

`$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';`

3. Change it to look like this:

`$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';`

4. Then, within that phpmyadmin dir, create a new folder & name it upload.
5. Take that large .sql file that you’re trying to import, and put it in that new upload folder.
6. Now, the next time you go to import a database into phpMyAdmin, you’ll see a new dropdown field right below the standard browse area in your “File to Import” section.

Answer (score 3):

For that you will have to edit `php.ini` file, If you are using the ubuntu server this is link [Upload large file in phpMyAdmin](http://www.technologiespost.com/2013/04/how-to-increase-phpmyadmin-upload-limit_8.html) might help you.

Comment: Thanks you, that was perfect.

Answer (score 3):

In MAMP, You could load huge files by :

1. creating a new folder in this directory
   /MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/"folderName"
2. and then edit "/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php"  line 531 :

   ```
      $cfg['UploadDir']= 'folderName';
   ```
3. Copy your .sql or .csv Files into this folder.
4. Now you will have another option in "PhpMyAdmin" : Select from the
   web server upload directory newFolder/:  You could select your file and import 
   it.

   You could load any file now !!

Answer (score 2):

the answer for those with shared hosting. Best to use this little script which I just used to import a 300mb DB file to my server. The script is called Big Dump.

[provides a script to import large DB's on resource-limited servers](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/)

Comment: This is actually good solution, but You got downvote because of URL which can be invalid one day. Please add some informations about this script, escpecially the name of it.

Comment: its called big dump it stops the SQL server from stopping or being interrupted when importing a large database file to the server. btw there are other answers with urls that could down at any moment and none of them are down voted

Answer (score 2):

First, copy your mysql database to local disk C:\ for easy file location and now open your command prompt.

Meawhile, Navigate to mysql bin folder eg if you are using xampp, run or type the code below.

cd/     This take you to local disk pointer
cd xampp    This take you to xampp folder
cd mysql   This take you to mysql folder
cd bin  This take you to bin folder

and run the code below

mysql -u dbusername -p  -D dbname < c:\yourdbtoupload.sql

This will promt enter password, enter your password or click enter button if you are not using password

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best way to upload a large file not use phpmyadmin . cause phpmyadin at first upload the file using php upload class then execute sql that cause most of the time its time out happened.

best way is : 
enter wamp folder>bin>mysql>bin dirrectory then write this line

**mysql -u root -p listnames < latestdb.sql**
here listnames is the database name at first please create the empty database 
and the latestdb.sql is your sql file name where your data present .

but one important thing is if your database file has unicode data . you must need to open your latestdb.sql file and one line before any line . the line is :

**SET NAMES utf8;**
then your command mode run this script code

Answer (score 1):

I have made a PHP script which is designed to import large database dumps which have been generated by phpmyadmin. It's called PETMI and you can download it here [[project page]](https://desbest.com/projects/petmi) [[gitlab page]](http://gitlab.com/desbest/petmi). It has been tested with a 1GB database.

Answer (score 0):

Change your server settings to allow file uploads larger than 12 mb and you should be fine.
Usually the server settings are set to 5 to 8 mb for file uploads.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11490510)

Comment: actually at the time this answer was posted, this was the most common error(3 years ago) that file uploads were default not big enough. He's using phpmyadmin == webinterface. import == upload from disc. upload == server settings. server settings == defaults which is at 5 or 8 mb 3 years ago. So I do not see how this does NOT provide an answer. Yes, I didn't lead him by the hand how to set up exactly becuase he hasn't provided which server he's using, apache, ngix, iis, other.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your sql file in a text editor (like Notepad)
2. Select All -> Copy
3. Go to phpMyAdmin, select your database and go to SQL tab
4. Paste the content you have copied in clipboard
5. It might popup a javascript error, ignore it
6. Execute

Comment: Not a good practice! Large texts will cause big problems when you do this. Best way is configure php.ini to allow large import or import through mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
```

First find this location -> open php.ini file in notepad or sublime text
Then find this "post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, memory_limit" in php.ini text and change size like below

```
post_max_size=450M

upload_max_filesize=450M

memory_limit=700M
```

**Notes : Before do this stop phpmyadmin in xampp or wamp and do above methods and then startall (xampp or manager-osx) it will work perfectly. Then you can able to upload large files in phpmyadmin. Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

[For windows, first of all open xampp and right click Config and open php.ini file. After in php.ini file update this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shkG6.png)

- post_max_size = 800M
- upload_max_filesize = 800M
- max_execution_time = 6000
- max_input_time = 6000
- memory_limit = 1000M