# Importing large SQL file in phpMyadmin

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a 5MB file in phpMyadmin.

When I follow the normal procedure of importing it just makes me wait and nothing is happening. Since yesterday morning that file is getting imported and it shows that moving circle sign above the browse.

Now when I followed the other method -

```
1 C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\config.inc.php

2 Find the line with $cfg['UploadDir'] on it and update it to:

3 $cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';

4 Create a directory called ‘upload’ within the phpmyadmin directory.

5 C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\upload\
```

I got this error -

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\import\sql.php on line 135
```

I checked the `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\import\sql.php` file but couldn't find anything like 300 or execution time.
Guys pls help me with how can I import this %MB file fast so that I can proceed with my tool development !!

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305516/how-to-import-large-sql-file-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: please check video here https://youtu.be/eTpVItabrjY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:Use below command

```
mysql -u root -p dbname
use dbname;
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
mysql> show tables;
SOURCE path (D:/your_file_name.sql); // please give correct path
```

Comment: For whose use windows:
1. Open cmd 
2. Navigate to your mysql\bin folder
3. run  mysql -u root -p dbname
use dbname;
SOURCE D:/your_file_name.sql

Comment: the path should be D:\your_file_name.sql for windows

Comment: Hi, I am getting prompt for the password but I haven't used any password, what do I do in this case

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using windows OS. So following step may solve your problem

1. Open cmd.
2. Navigate mysql installation directory [type command cd "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12(May be different version)\bin"]
3. now write command  `mysql -u <user> -p <password> <dbmame> < C:/path/of/file.sql`

This trick work for me.

Comment: Linux doesn't accept passwords in the command; this command worked for me: `mysql -u <user> -p <dbmame> < C:/path/of/file.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql console to import large sql file.

Type the below command in mysql console:

```
SOURCE "Path of your file located and mention your file name"

For Ex: SOURCE C:\Users\test\Desktop\.sql
```

OR : Update the value in php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize=128M
post_max_size = 128M
max_execution_time = 300  
max_input_time = 300
```

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Ensure that these options match your needs in php.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize=2M
max_execution_time=300
post_max_size=8M
```