# how to upload a large sql file in phpmyadmin on server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel

How can i upload a large sql file in phpmyadmin on server. I'm trying to migrate my wordpress website from localhost to online but when i'm trying to upload my sql file which is large then 50 MB it show error. I have only cpanel access.

Comment: see video here https://youtu.be/eTpVItabrjY

Answer (score 1):

modify two limit options in 'php.ini'

```
// larger than 50M
upload_max_filesize = 00M
post_max_size = 00M
```

Comment: i'm tried to find php.ini file on cpanel but can't.

Comment: Did you restart the web server?

Comment: NO,Please Help Me how to do this, because there is no any option to restart web server in cpanel

Comment: He's using a mere cPanel, he probably needs to write a small PHP script to fetch the file (from some provider, maybe Dropbox) and then import it programmatically to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload large .sql file in two way.

1.Edit the php.ini page

```
post_max_size = 800M 
upload_max_filesize = 800M 
max_execution_time = 5000 
max_input_time = 5000 
memory_limit = 1000M
```

most of the case the execution time will be time out and fail the upload.

2. so that use the command line if you have back end access.

   mysql -p -u your_username your_database_name < file.sql

   mysql -p -u example example_live < /home2/example/public_html/file.sql

/home2/example/public_html/file.sql (file path)

Answer (score 1):

Given the limitations your host places on your account, I think your best solution is to use the phpMyAdmin "[UploadDir](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir)" feature.

You'll need to be able to control the configuration of your phpMyAdmin, which probably means you'll need to install your own copy to your web space, but that's [relatively easy](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install). Then you'll have to modify your `config.inc.php` to add a line like `$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';` (you can use any directory name here). Next, create the directory and upload your SQL file there using SFTP, SSH, or whatever other means your host gives you of interacting with your files. Now the file should appear in a dropdown on the Import tab.

Comment: Good to know! Can be useful to know

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your SQL file into smaller SQL files.

To do this when you export from localhost, only choose a few tables to export at a time (you may have to choose the Custom export method).

Basically you need to make every SQL file smaller than 50MB. You can then import each SQL file, one by one.

Comment: i upload sql file after make it zip and it uploaded successfully, but now when i'm export sql file it not export all data

Answer (score 0):

You can compress your sql file, then upload the sql zip file to the server. If the file size is still higher than limit stated in your server, you may need to increase the limits as explained by @DongHyun.

However, most shared hosting plans don't allow PHP.ini editing. In that case, contacting customer support might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import it from mysql console as per the taste of your OS.

```
mysql -u {DB-USER-NAME} -p {DB-NAME} < {db.file.sql path}
```

or if it's on a remote server use the -h flag to specify the host.

```
mysql -u {DB-USER-NAME} -h {MySQL-SERVER-HOST-NAME} -p {DB-NAME} < {db.file.sql path}
```

[for more example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305516/how-to-import-large-sql-file-in-phpmyadmin)