# MYSQL : How to Import Large DB without slowly?

Tags: mysql, import

I want to import a big SQL file(2.5GB) into Mysql.I try to import it with import section in phpMyAdmin and i waited more than one hour in one of my table which has more then 500000 rows.

I am Using

```
PHP 7.3.9
phpMyAdmin 4.9.0.1
Operating System Windows Server 2012 R2
34078MB RAM
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.0GHz Processor
with Xampp Server
```

Is there any way to Speed Up My Import ?

Comment: Use a faster internet?

Comment: And use MySQL cli for importing large amounts of data, not phpmyadim.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305516/how-to-import-large-sql-file-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: i already copy sql dump file to Windows Server

Answer (score 2):

The fastest import in MySQL works using the command line interface on the local server where the mysql is installed. If you do not have access to the server console, the import will be dependent on many parameters like network speed, I/O throughput and the mediator interface's efficiency which is phpMyAdmin in your case.

If you have access to the command line interface, copy the file to the remote server and use below command for import which will be much faster:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,i use this one it also get some times,what is the default time for 1 GB data base import and export are you have any idea for it.

Comment: As I said, performance is dependent on several factors, but usually, a 1 GB file only takes a minute or 2 on the servers I have worked on.