# Trying to import 11GB+ SQL file to mysql

Tags: mysql, import, xampp

For an ongoing project I need to install a local server using XAMPP. The colleague exported the mySQL DB from his nGINX environment (I suppose it uses the same mySQL as my apache) but the size is an insane 11GB+. In order to prepare, I did the necessary *php.ini* modifications listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305516/how-to-import-large-sql-file-in-phpmyadmin), entered `myisam_sort_buffer_size=16384M` to *my.ini* and also followed a step-by-step tutorial from [here](https://thecodedeveloper.com/import-large-sql-files-xampp/). I have 8GB DDR4 RAM and 8th generation i3, so this should not be a problem. The SQL import was running from 0:30 to 14:30 when I noticed that it simply stopped.

Unfortunately the shell import command seems to stop at the 13149th line of the 18061 lines. I see no error messages, and I do not see the imported database in phpMyAdmin. I see the flashing underscore, but no more SQL commands are executed.

I am wondering if there is a solution to this - I want to ensure that the cc 14 hours of processing does not go to waste, so my question is:

**If I terminate the ongoing but seemingly frozen CMD, can I continue importing the remaining 4912 lines from a separate SQL file?**

Answer (score 0):

16GB sort buffer size is absurdly high. I suspect you mean maximum_packet_size, and even for that you pobably men 16M rather than 16G.

If you are certain which line is stuck yes, you can resume from there, including the line that failed.