# Can't import database through phpmyadmin file

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to import Database through phpMyAdmin. My database file is a.sql and it's size is 200MB I am trying to import this on local and phpMyAdmin is saying:

You probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit.

i am try to edit  php.ini

```
 php_value upload_max_filesize 220M //file size
 php_value post_max_size 220M
 php_value max_execution_time 200
 php_value max_input_time 200
```

Please help I really need this to work.

Comment: i am updateing hte question

Comment: After you edited php.ini, did you restart the server?

Comment: i m restarting the server but can not worked

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't import database through phpmyadmin file size too large](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593128/cant-import-database-through-phpmyadmin-file-size-too-large)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command.

```
mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u username -p databasename | gzip > database-2014-06-16.gz
```

In this way, you can save gz (compressed) format of database dump

Answer (score -1):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 220M //file size
php_value post_max_size 220M
```

This values are related to php itself not phpmyadmin.