# How to change import limit on phpmyadmin running with wampserver?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I can only upload files up to 128 MB big on Phpmyadmin. I need to change the value, so I tried to change the php.ini file via tray.

[image]

I already changed `memory_limit = 128M` to `memory_limit = 2048M` and restarted all services, but the limit in Phpmyadmin is still 128 MB.

Do I have to change another setting?

[image]

---

**Update:**

I figured out that you can also set it directly via the tray menu, but it makes no difference (restarted already):

[image]

Interestingly there is still 128M selected even after I changed it to 2048M in the *php.ini*. I set it to 2048M again via the tray menu.

---

- **memory_limit** = 2048M
- **post_max_size** = 2048M
- **upload_max_filesize** = 2048M
- **max_execution_time** = 300
- **max_input_time** = 300

Made no difference.

---

The duplicate  ['Can not increase file upload size WAMP'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604640/can-not-increase-file-upload-size-wamp) solved the problem.

Comment: Make sure you are changing the correct `.ini` file.

Comment: @Script47, I assume that this is the right file, since it is in the tray.

Comment: Shot in the dark but what if you stopped -> restarted?

Comment: compress your file with .zip extension and then try again

Comment: @Script47, I tried it, made no difference. +Rajinder, this does not answer the question, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: also make sure your restart your wamp server after making changes in .ini file

Comment: @Black can you open the actual PHP ini file and check if it has actually changed?

Comment: @Rajinder OP has already restated / stopped and restarted.

Comment: @Script47, I opened the php.ini file and it actually changed.

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate. The solution does not work.

Comment: This is still a problem and it's 2023....

Comment: Found the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916516/wampserver-phpmyadmin-maximum-execution-time-of-360-seconds-exceeded   Modify the file \wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf