# Why is phpmyadmin reading incorrect value from php.ini?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I temporarily edited the file `wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.7.9\libraries\Util.php` for debugging purposed. I changed the class `generateHiddenMaxFileSize` to the following:

```
//shows the output in the `import` section in phpmyadmin
public static function generateHiddenMaxFileSize($max_size)
{
    $out1 = php_ini_loaded_file();  //output: E:\Entwicklung\Programme\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\bin\php.ini
    $out2 = ini_get("upload_max_filesize"); //output: 128M

    return "<p>php.ini: $out1</p><br><p>$out2</p>";
}
```

I expected the value from the key `upload_max_filesize` from the file `wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\bin\php.ini`, which is `2048M`, but It returns `128M` instead.

[image]

**php.ini (snippet)**

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
```

I also used `ini_get` to output other values and changed them to see if the problem is only with **upload_max_filesize**, e.g. I changed `serialize_precision` to another value and returned the value to the view with `ini_get("serialize_precision");`. The change was regocnized and displayed correctly.

I already restarted all the services. Why do I get `128M` instead of `2048M`?

---

I am debugging it to find the solution for this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552990/how-to-change-import-limit-on-phpmyadmin-running-with-wampserver).

---

**The duplicate solved my question.**

Comment: what's the value of `post_max_size`?

Comment: Its `2048M` but it should not mather because I executed `ini_get("upload_max_filesize");` not `ini_get("post_max_size");`

Comment: what's the output of `php -i | grep "upload_max_filesize"`?

Comment: @Federkun, I get `upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M`