# Database can not import in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to import a database but a warning is displayed as below

> error  phpmyadmin.POST Content-Length of 3617 bytes exceeds the limit of 128 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't import database through phpmyadmin file size too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593128/cant-import-database-through-phpmyadmin-file-size-too-large)

Comment: You can import database via terminal like this :- 
mysql -u <username> -p <databasename> < <filename.sql>

Comment: I suggest that you change the `post_max_size` to 16M in the `php.ini` file, restart the Apache and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do

1. Go to XAMPP installed directoy C:\xampp\php
2. Open the "Configuration Settings" file named php.ini using your text
   editor.
3. Update upload_max_filesize = 128M
4. Similarly update post_max_size = 128M
5. Then max_execution_time = 200
6. And max_input_time = 200
7. Restart XAMPP to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

try to import command line ,by using this command

```
mysql -u mysql_user -p DATABASE < backup.sql
```