# phpmyadmin does not recognize updated upload_max_filesize after restart

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I want to import a large database to phpmyadmin. Based on the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593128/cant-import-database-through-phpmyadmin-file-size-too-large) and the standard documentation link provided in the error below:

> You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit.

I have updated the php.ini configs and restarted my server. However, I still get the same error message and see 128 as the max file size as you can see below:

[image]

Here's what I have on my php.ini now:

`upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
max_execution_time = 1200
max_input_time = 600`

I am using WAMP with php 7.2 and restarted my services after making the changes. Any ideas on why the error is not resolved?

Comment: Did you also change the `post_max_size`? It's been a while, but I believe it was two settings in the php.ini that have to changed for phpmyadmin uploads.

Comment: Yes. Updated the question to include what I changed.

Comment: I know this is a terrible "Did you turn it off and back on" question and I hope you forgive me for it, but just to cover the bases. Specifically did you restart PHP and Apache services?

Comment: That's a great question @JNevill. I'm using WAMP and did "restart all services" which includes PHP, Apache, and MySQL. Just to be safe. I will close and run again.

Comment: The only thing left after that is to make sure you are editing the right php.ini. I'm not familiar with your server set up though, so I can't offer any guidance there besides to double check that you've got the right php.ini.

Comment: I noticed I have multiple php.inis earlier and updated the one WAMP uses. I'll dig more and report back. Thanks.

Comment: See the DUP. These parameters are in the Alias that makes `phpMyAdmin work. That is where you need to change these values