# How to import large (GB) SQL file in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

ERROR: You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit.

I want to import a sql file of approx 2.5GB But it dont accept that kind of big file, is there an alternative of doing this without splitting the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't import database through phpmyadmin file size too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593128/cant-import-database-through-phpmyadmin-file-size-too-large)

Comment: tried it but my sql file is to large

Comment: You tried all the solutions in the link and none worked?

Comment: yeah, the sql file is 2.5GB phpmyadmin not accepting it